# JsonSchema Validation Exception

Tags: jsonschema, rest-assured, json-schema-validator, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am trying to to do Json Schema validation in restassured by matching response body with JsonSchema in class path . I am getting following error

io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Non-standard token 'NaN': enable JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS to allow
at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 3948]

Response body contains the following values  "20": NaN, "21": NaN, "22": NaN, "23": NaN, "24": NaN, "25": ""25minutes"", "26": NaN, "27": NaN, "28": NaN, "29": NaN, which causes the problem.How can i avoid this error. Pls someone help.

Comment: `NaN` is not a data-type in json, then jackson can't parse it.

Answer (score 1):

`NaN` is not valid JSON.

[Reference](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)